# How can i get my controller transition animation to work properly in both portrait and landscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiviewanimation

I have a UICollectionView cell. When the user selects it, I am trying to do a custom navigation controller animation to the next viewController view.

Basically I'm

1. adding the new view controller's view as a subview
2. Setting the frame of the new view to be as small as possible, (i.e 0.01, 0.01)
3. Setting the center of the new view frame to the center of the selected collectionView cell
4. Then run an animation block that changes the frame of the new view to equal [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].
5. and finally onComplete, push on the new viewController

SO I can see the animation start from within the cell frame (although it's not quite centered), and it expands to the screen portrait dimensions, even if the cell frame is in the bottom corner of the screen; which is good.

The problem is in landscape mode, the dimensions are still expanding to portrait specs. shouldn't the values of [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] have changed since rotation?

Here's the code

```
DetailsViewController *details = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithItem:item];

[[self view] addSubview:details.view];
details.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0.01, 0.01);
details.view.center = cell.center;

[UIView animateWithDuration:[duration floatValue] animations:^{
    details.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
}
 completion:^(BOOL finished){
     [[self navigationController] pushViewController:details animated:NO];
 }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] is orientation-independent. Consider using the superview's frame instead.